# Nikon AF 70-300 mm lens zoom broken, can it be salvaged?

Tags: lens, zoom

So I accidentally dropped my Nikkor AF 70-300 mm lens on the floor (yes, stupid).

Now the zoom ring does not work. When I turn it, nothing happens. However, I can slide the lens back and forth, and zoom in and out that way. The zoom ring does not move when I do that. Other than that, the lens seems fine:

- No noticeable difference on pictures taken
- Focus works, both manual and auto

It is like there is no longer a connection between the zoom ring and the actual lens. Can this be fixed ? By a professional or can I do it myself ?

Comment: Had a similar experience with my 24-70. Repair cost $699. Won't do THAT again!

Comment: I have the same problem, can you fix yours??? And maybe is something disconnected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the optics are still ok, it can certainly be fixed by Nikon, even if they have to discard the entire body and give you a new body, if the optics are ok, that's a large portion of the cost.

You might or might not be able to fix it yourself depending on how the case was damaged, but there also may likely be alignment issues as well, so it's probably best to have a Nikon service center do it.